# configuring .gems file (rails apps on Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, heroku, rubygems

I'm learning how to deploy RoR (v2.3.4) on Heroku. Last night was my first attempt at pushing an app with an external gem (active_merchant).

What is the URL format for configuring the .gems file? (My last attempt was 'active_merchant --source github.com/Shopify/active_merchant'.)

Any inputs would be great. Thanks.

-BrianP. (bjpcjp@gmail.com)

Answer (score 2):

According to [Heroku's docs](http://docs.heroku.com/gems), it's the same as you'd pass to the `gem` command line tool. In your instance, I believe you'd do:

```
shopify-active_merchant --source gems.github.com
```

However, is there a reason you're trying to install it off Github? [Github's gem hosting is deprecated](http://github.com/blog/515-gem-building-is-defunct), and you it doesn't look like Shopify actually hosted versions there anyway (the [Active Merchant page](http://www.activemerchant.org/) suggests you run `gem install activemerchant`).

Comment: Tks Rufo, I used gem install activemerchant to config my local machine. The Git push to Heroku failed - hence the question.